# Matching multiple conditions and returning/appending multiple results, between two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm very new to python and really don't know where to start doing the following:
I have two dataframes, df1 and df2.

```py
df1
  fruit    id   date
0 apple    2    01/10/20
1 pear     1    15/09/20
2 banana   3    01/06/20
3 peach    4    10/04/20
```

```py
df2
  name      uid     ndate
0  paul      2    02/11/20
1  tracy     1    15/12/20
2  iain      3    01/05/20
3  frida     4    23/02/20
4  david     2    06/06/20
5  peter     3    19/11/20  
6  adam      4    07/03/20
7  eve       1    30/11/20
8  hannah    2    25/09/20
9  janine    2    13/08/20
10 charlotte 5    10/04/20
```

I want to map 'name' values from df2 to new columns in df1.
There are two conditions to be met, first that the 'uid' in df2 must be the same as the 'id' in df1,
and the second that the ***'ndate' in df2 must be before (less than) the 'date' in df1***.
Ideally ***each matched value should return to new columns to the right of date in df1***.

```py
df1
  fruit    id   date       match1   match2   match3 ...(etc)
0 apple    2    01/10/20   david    hannah   janine
1 pear     1    15/09/20   
2 banana   3    01/06/20   iain
3 peach    4    10/04/20   frida    adam
```

Hope this makes sense, I've simplified the tables as much as possible, and this is the gist of what I'm looking to do. Any suggestions much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.merge(df2,left_on=['id','date'],right_on=['uid','ndate'])
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work as ndate in df2 must be less than date in df1, not equal to. Also I think this would add multiple new rows with multiple results, when what I'd like is to add multiple new values/columns to the right of the original df1.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This code doesn't answer the question, sorry.